# re.search not returning a match with (seemingly) correct regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a simple regex match to extract parts of a dms coordinate.

The regex seems solid enough, when copying the below to [regexr](https://regexr.com/) i get a match:

```
regex: ^([0-9]{1,2})[:|°| ]([0-9]{1,2})[:|'|′| ]?([0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]+){0,1})?[\"|″| ]([N|S])$
body: 51°30'30.7080"N
```

In my python script i have to following:

```
# coding: utf8
import re
dms_regex = "^([0-9]{1,2})[:|°| ]([0-9]{1,2})[:|'|′| ]?([0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]+){0,1})?[\"|″| ]([N|S])$"

def dmsToCoordinates(dms_lat):
    print(dms_lat)
    matches = re.search(dms_regex, dms_lat)
    print(matches)

dmsToCoordinates("51°30'30.7080\"N")
```

My terminal output is:

```
51°30'30.7080"N
None
```

Obviously I expect to get a match.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong before i throw myself out of the window.

Comment: Probably, there are some invisible characters somewhere. Try adding `\W*` after `^` and before `$`. Also, remove redundant `|`s, see https://regex101.com/r/jB3370/1

Comment: I get `<re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='51°30\'30.7080"N'>` as output.

Comment: Not sure if it's worth adding, but I have the encoding set to utf-8 (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- is the first line of my file)

Comment: Did you copy-paste that string literal from somewhere? Or type it by hand? I suspect non-printable characters there.

Comment: @AndrasDeak copied from google

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: You could check`from unicodedata import name; for c in dms_lat: print(name(c))` and find the culprit.

Comment: And of course type a clean string by hand, since your code works.

Comment: @AndrasDeak tried with typed characters in the regex pattern & string, but the same result.  The for loop gives me a `TypeError: name() argument 1 must be unicode, not str` (thanks for the help so far)

Comment: That sounds like python 2....

Comment: @AndrasDeak ran the script out of my venv by mistake, yikes :s.  This is working fine in python 3, if you want to add a response to that end the points are yours

Comment: @User632716 thanks, I decided to indeed add an answer, because even knowing that it was due to the wrong python version I found the issue confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out (mostly by accident) in the comment thread on the question: you were using the wrong (old) version of python by mistake.

One of the main problems (if not *the* main problem) with python 2 was how handling strings was completely broken. The `str` type was a bytestring, with a separate unicode type for unicode text. This mushed together what's text and what's data.

So when you entered a non-ascii character (such as the degree sign) and ran your code in python 2, this happened:

```
>>> '°'
'\xc2\xb0'
>>> len('°')
2
>>> '°'.decode('utf8')
u'\xb0'
>>> len('°'.decode('utf8'))
1
```

The `'°'` (byte)string literal becomes two bytes as data, but still masquerading as a string! It's only a proper single-character string if you encode it and end up with a unicode string. So when you put it into a character class:

```
>>> 'f[°]oo'
'f[\xc2\xb0]oo'
```

the two bytes will act like two characters in the character class, one `'\xc2'`, the other `'\xb0'`. This means it won't match the `'\xc2\xb0'` bytes is inserted instead of another literal degree sign in the target string:

```
>>> re.search('f[°]oo', 'f°oo') is None
True
>>> re.search('f[\xc2\xb0]oo', 'f\xc2\xb0oo') is None # exact same thing as previous
True
>>> re.search('f[\xc2\xb0]oo', 'f\xc2oo') is None
False
```

So your accidental use of python 2 caused the regex to break on the non-ascii characters, which is fundamentally due to how strings are broken in python 2. If someone were to use the code in python 2 they would at least have to switch to `u''` unicode literals in both the pattern and the target, which would magically fix the problem.

And two general notes about your regex:

1. you should remove all those pipes from your character classes. Character classes mean "use a character from this bag of characters", meaning that

   (a) pipes aren't needed to enforce the choice between characters in the character class, and

   (b) it will match actual pipes in the target: `re.search('[a|b]','|') is not None`
2. you should use *raw* string literals for representing regular expressions, otherwise you would occasionally have to escape the backslashes in escape sequences in order to get a proper match and prevent ambiguity.

So I suggest this pattern instead:

```
dms_regex = r"^([0-9]{1,2})[:° ]([0-9]{1,2})[:'′ ]?([0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]+){0,1})?[\"″ ]([NS])$"
```